# Why does my rear derailleur keep breaking?

Tags: derailleur, mechanical

I upgraded my rear-mech with a new cassette, chain and new cables a few weeks ago since then i've mangled two rear mechs!

Both times I've just been riding along; not in a big gear; not at the extremes of the cassette, the mech just seems to get caught on something (the chain?) and bends and snaps!

I've got to buy a 3rd mech and I'm wondering why it's happening, is it just bad luck?

The mech I replaced (an ageing XTR) I'd had for years without any miss-hap but now I've mangled two XT mechs, one was a Shadow and the one prior to that was a standard.

Any sugggestions?

Comment: Is your derailer hanger bent?  Does the derailer point straight vertically? Is it possible that it's shifting into the spokes? Did you try shifting through all the gears while it was up in a repair stand and seeing what the derailer does?

Comment: The hanger is fine.. The bike is steel and after the first mech went the hanger was bent but got it straightened and mech replaced at my LBS. Just to emphasises, the mech was nowhere near the spokes..! :o|

Comment: @Dog Ears: Pictures might help folks diagnose this, particularly pics of the broken deraileurs if you have them.

Comment: For other Americans: "mech" is British for "derailer" (French, dérailleur).  Sheldon on spelling this word: http://www.sheldonbrown.com/derailer.html

Comment: Maybe front sprocket is damaged and grabs the chain? Or the rear mech hook is bent?

Comment: @Drew Stephens, @Dog Ears: Is the "mechanical" tag we've adopted going to imply deraileur-only to folks in England?

Comment: @neilfein, to me 'mechanical' implies a (mechanical) break-down. like a snapped chain or a cable or a broken mech/derailleru in this case.

Comment: I am having the Same problem except mine has done it 4 times and I have replaced the hanger twice and the chain once. my only idea is that I bent the hub in my rear rim. I was informed by my good friend who is always working on bikes that he had that happen to him. He said it messed up his whole rear end of his bike. My other opinion is that could my frame be bent? How could I tell?

Comment: You sure the derailer's not getting into the spokes?  Do you have a spoke guard?

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. This site, like all Stack Exchange sites, is not a typical forum. Users post questions and the community attempts to answer the question. Since this post purposes unsupported suppositions, it would be better suited as a comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you change the chain after the first derailleur broke?  If the same chain was on and you're positive the derailleur didn't connect with the spokes, then the chain is a likely culprit.  Another thing to watch out for is loose pannier straps (or anything else that could get caught in the chain and take out the derailleur).

Comment: I think your right the chain was re-joined without using the correct replacement Shimano pin thingy.

Comment: @Dog Ears: Glad you found it!

Answer (score 5):

It turns out that this could have been caused by breaking and joining a Shimano chain without using the correct connector pin.  The final time I got the derailer replaced along with the chain and it's been fine.

Comment: Mine broke when I joined the failed chain likely wrongly in the middle of the night under the bicycle light, and then attempted to ride.

Answer (score 3):

If your chain is too long, and you are in the 'small-small' combination, it is possible for the derailleur to sort of fold up on itself. Flip your bike over and put it in the smallest gear up front and the smallest gear in the rear and make sure the chain isn't rubbing on the derailleur.